# Haskell function to format a floating-point number with some precision

Tags: haskell, formatting, floating-point

I have not yet developed a satisfying coding style in Haskell. In the code snippet below, there is a lot wrong to my taste:

- Helper functions which should be local to `showEngFloat` are defined outside.
- `let ... in` indentation madness
- More than 80 columns

Can you show me how this same code can be written in a less indentation and pollution prone way?

I am aware that the name I chose for my function is not well chosen. (`show...` functions should return a `ShowS` type, right?)

```
import Numeric

normalize :: Int -> (Int,Int)
normalize dp =
    loop dp 0
    where
        loop dp e
            | dp > 3 = loop (dp - 3) (e+3)
            | dp < 1 = loop (dp + 3) (e-3)
            | otherwise = (dp,e)

toString :: [Int] -> [Char]            
toString ia = concat (fmap show ia)

padZeroes nz v  = v ++ take nz (repeat '0')

showEngFloat :: RealFloat a => Int -> a -> [Char]
showEngFloat precision x
    | x >= 0.0 = calc x
    | otherwise = "-" ++ calc (-x)
    where
        calc n =
            let (digits,dotPos0) = floatToDigits 10 n in
                let (ndigits,(dotPos1,e)) = (length digits,normalize dotPos0) in
                    let a
                            | ndigits >= dotPos1 = toString (take dotPos1 digits)
                            | otherwise = padZeroes (dotPos1 - ndigits) (toString (take ndigits digits))
                            in
                            let b = padZeroes (precision - max dotPos1 ndigits) (toString (drop dotPos1 digits))
                                in
                                    let c = toString [e] in
                                        a ++ "." ++ b ++ "E" ++ c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about floating out subfunctions and factoring lets ?

```
calc :: RealFloat a => a -> Int -> [Char]
calc n precision =
  let (digits,dotPos0) = floatToDigits 10 n 
      (ndigits,(dotPos1,e)) = (length digits,normalize dotPos0)
      b = padZeroes (precision - max dotPos1 ndigits) (toString (drop dotPos1 digits))
      c = toString [e]
      a
        | ndigits >= dotPos1 = toString (take dotPos1 digits)
        | otherwise = padZeroes (dotPos1 - ndigits) (toString (take ndigits digits)) in
      a ++ "." ++ b ++ "E" ++ c

showEngFloat :: RealFloat a => Int -> a -> [Char]
showEngFloat precision x
    | x >= 0.0 = calc x precision
    | otherwise = "-" ++ calc (-x) precision
```

You can probably rewrite this further still.

Comment: Those extra functions are (in my eyes) implementation details of the main function. Moving them outside pollutes the namespace, I think. Probably suggests to potential users of the module that those implementation helpers actually are part of an "official" API...

Comment: Your module's header filters which functions it exports. This is where you avoid namespace pollution.

Comment: Why do ``a`` and ``b`` need extra lets and the second line in first let does not?

Comment: They actually don't. Look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to write it (without changing too much). The functions `toString` and `padZereos` do sensible things on their own, so I kept them in the global namespace. Everything else is local. Having one big where-clause where you define everything local to a function is something you'll see often. Note that due to lazy evaluation you can define `a_trimmed` and `a_padded`, even if only one is used, so the other is never calculated. That further cleans up the code.

In a next step, I'd probably get rid of `calc` entirely, and fold sign handling into its body. Also, `normalize` looks like it should be calculated with `divMod` or `quotRem`.

```
showEngFloat :: RealFloat a => Int -> a -> [Char]
showEngFloat precision x = result where
  result = if x >= 0 then calc x else '-' : calc (-x)
  normalize :: Int -> (Int,Int)
  normalize dp = loop dp 0 where
    loop dp e
      | dp > 3 = loop (dp - 3) (e+3)
      | dp < 1 = loop (dp + 3) (e-3)
      | otherwise = (dp,e)
  calc n = a ++ "." ++ b ++ "E" ++ c where
    (digits,dotPos0) = floatToDigits 10 n
    ndigits = length digits
    (dotPos1,e) = normalize dotPos0
    a_trimmed = toString (take dotPos1 digits)
    a_padded  = padZeroes (dotPos1 - ndigits) (toString (take ndigits digits))
    a = if ndigits >= dotPos1 then a_trimmed else a_padded
    b = padZeroes (precision - max dotPos1 ndigits) (toString (drop dotPos1 digits))
    c = toString [e]
```

Comment: This is about the version I had in mind when I started. Then I ran into troubles and ended with the terrible stuff I showed :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll hijack dirkt's solution and add my two cents.

```
showEngFloat :: RealFloat a => Int -> a -> [Char]
showEngFloat precision x
  =  if x >= 0 then "" else "-"
  ++ padZeroes dotPos1 digitstring
  ++ "."
  ++ padZeroes precision (drop dotPos1 digitstring)
  ++ "E"
  ++ show (e * 3) where
  (digits,dotPos0) = floatToDigits 10 (abs x)
  digitstring = foldMap show digits
  (e, dotPos1) = divMod dotPos0 3

padZeroes l v = take l (v ++ repeat '0')
```

(Not quite sure plugging `precision` into `padZeroes` directly is right.)